# Why compiler report 'may be used uninitialised in this function'?

Tags: c, initialization, compiler-warnings

I'm writing a linux module, here are the code fragment.And it
complains of unitialized using of variable,but I think I've checked
there is enough checking before using it.I think it may be related be 
ERR_PTR and PTR_ERR macro,but I don't know why.
Would someone please help to explain it? Thank you in advance.

```
static inline void * __must_check ERR_PTR(long error)
{
    return (void *) error;
}

static inline long __must_check PTR_ERR(__force const void *ptr)
{
    return (long) ptr;
}

#define MAX_ERRNO       4095
#define IS_ERR_VALUE(x) unlikely((x) >= (unsigned long)-MAX_ERRNO)


static inline bool __must_check IS_ERR(__force const void *ptr)
{
    return IS_ERR_VALUE((unsigned long)ptr);
}

void* test_alloc_value(void)
{
    char* p = kmalloc(100,GFP_KERNEL);
    if(!p)  
            return ERR_PTR(-ENOMEM);
    memset(p,100,0);
    return p;
}

int test_value_get(int *value)
{
    int err = 0;
    char *p;

    p = test_alloc_value();

    if (IS_ERR(p))
            return PTR_ERR(p);

    *value = *p;
    return err;
}

void my_test(void)
{
    int test_value;
    int err = test_value_get(&test_value);
    if(err)
            return err;
    if(test_value) //warnings,see below
            return 0;

}
```

The error message is:

```
warning: ‘test_value’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
if(test_value)
   ^
```

---

Update: 01-30-2015:

I think the root cause would be the `long` to `int` conversion. The `PTR_ERR()` function would convert a pointer to `long`,but in 
above code,`test_value_get()` would convert a `long` into `int`,and return it
to `my_test()` .Since I'm using a 64bit machine,the long would possibly 
be cut off to lower 32bits,for example,if it is 0xfffffffe00000000,
the return value would be cut to 0,and then `if(err)` would not satisfy,
which caused the `test_value` be used in a wrong manner.
(Although the errno would not be greater than 4095,compiler seemed not be aware of it,the nearest overflow value would be 0xfffffffe00000000)
Any comments?

Comment: Where is test_value declared?

Comment: `int test_value` is a global?

Comment: Obviously not your full code, but in `test_value_get`, not all possible paths change (initialize) `test_value` (a.k.a. `value`) in the function.

Comment: Only seeing this code, *it could be* unitialized!

Comment: If `test_value` has static storage duration, it is zero-initialized per the standard, and I don't see how it can be anything but touting static storage duration given what little code you've posted. C11 §6.7.9 Initialization,p10, "if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;" If it is otherwise, *post an MCVE* please.

Comment: Hi,guys ,I've updated the content,would you please help to see,thanks

Comment: What is `__must_check`

Comment: @Matt McNabb    #define __must_check                    __attribute__((warn_unused_result))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the below execution chain

1. In `my_test()`, `test_value_get()` gets called.
2. `test_alloc_value();` fails, `if (IS_ERR(p))` is TRUE.
3. `*value = *p;` is not executed.
4. in `my_test()`, `if(test_value)` exhibits `read-before-write` scenario.

It means, hoever less probable it might be, there is still a way,  *`test_value` may be used uninitialized*. So, isn't your compiler right?

To avoid this, in error case [`if (IS_ERR(p))` is TRUE.] also, initialize `*value` to some default value, like `0`.

```
if (IS_ERR(p))
{
       if (value)                 //NULL pointer safe
            *value = 0;             // set *value in error case also
            return PTR_ERR(p);
}
```

Comment: The fix for OPs code could be setting `*value` to zero if `IS_ERR(p)` is true.

Comment: @meskobalazs Very right sir. I was updating that only. :-)

Comment: There is no way that `test_value` is uninitialized. In your execution chain, `if(err)` would necessarily be true, leading to a `return`, so the control flow would never reach `if(test_value)`. The only problem is that the compiler does not realize that. That is, the warning is a false positive.

Comment: @sepp2k you're very right sir, but just to be 100% sure, we need to see `PTR_ERR` definition. Without that, well, technically , there's a possibility [I am hoping I should be wrong, though]. :-)

Comment: Hi,I've updated the content,would you please help to see,thanks